# Laravel5.4 で resources/views/layouts.blade.php の エラーを解決したい

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

#### 前提・実現したいこと

現在、Laravel5.4.23にて、共通レイアウト用のBladeファイルと、そのリンク先の個々のユーザー専用コンテンツ設定ページを作っています。

Bladeファイルのリンクを設定する際に、以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。エラーなく、設定変更できるようにするにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？
尚、共通レイアウト用Bladeファイルの 56 ~ 57 行目のアンカータグの中身を/cannel等に変更した場合は、特にエラーは表示されておりません。完全版ソースのアップロードもできますので、お申し付けください。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
(3/3) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/thbc002/Downloads/Code/8282_Code/takatube/takatube/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /Users/thbc002/Downloads/Code/8282_Code/takatube/takatube/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

(2/3) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/thbc002/Downloads/Code/8282_Code/takatube/takatube/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

(1/3) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object
>
```

下記は共通レイアウト用の `/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` になります。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">ログイン</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">新規登録</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="/account">アカウント設定</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/channel/{{ Auth::user()->channels()->first()->slug }}">私のチャンネル</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/channel/{{ Auth::user()->channels()->first()->slug }}/settings">チャンネル設定</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            ログアウト
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### 試したこと

```
php artisan make:auth
```

データベースを作成し、マイグレーションファイルをの生成と修正をした後に、model と controller の作成をして、マイグレーションを実行しました。

`/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` は、下記の状態です。

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

生成したマイグレーションファイル
の `/database/migrations/2018_04_05_021909_create_channels_table.php` は、下記のように修正しました。

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateChannelsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('channels', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('cover')->nullable();
            $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('channels');
    }
}
```

`/app/User.php` に、下記の内容を追加しました。

```
public function channels(){
    return $this->hasMany(Channel::class);
}
```

現在のところ、`/app/User.phpUser.php` は下記のようになっております。

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function channels(){
        return $this->hasMany(Channel::class);
    }
}
```

`/app/Channel.php` は、下記のような状態です。

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Channel extends Model
{

    use Searchable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'description',
        'cover',
        'avatar',
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    // getRouteKeyNameメソッドは、urlのパーマリンクをidではなく、slugで表示・処理させるためのメソッド
    public function getRouteKeyName(){
        return 'slug';
    }

}
```

`/app/Http/Controllers/ChannelController.php` は、下記の状態です。

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Jobs\UploadChannelCoverImage;
use App\Jobs\UploadProfileImage;

use App\Channel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChannelController extends Controller
{

  public function show(Channel $channel){
    return view('channel.show', [
          'channel' => $channel
    ]);
  }

  public function edit(Channel $channel){

        $this->authorize('edit', $channel);

        return view('channel.settings', [
            'channel' => $channel
        ]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Channel $channel){

        $this->authorize('update', $channel);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:channels,name,' . $channel->id,
            'slug' => 'required|max:255|alpha_num|unique:channels,slug,' . $channel->id
        ]);

        if($request->file('cover')){
           $request->file('cover')->move(storage_path() . "/uploads", $fileId = uniqid(true));
           $this->dispatch(new UploadChannelCoverImage($channel, $fileId));
        }

        if($request->file('avatar')){
          $request->file('avatar')->move(storage_path() . "/uploads", $fileId = uniqid(true));
          $this->dispatch(new UploadProfileImage($channel, $fileId));
        }


        $channel->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'slug' => $request->slug,
            'description' => $request->description
        ]);

        return redirect()->to("/channel/{$channel->slug}/settings");

    }
}
```

ルーティングは、`/routes/web.php` に、下記のものです。

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/search', 'SearchController@index')->name('search');


Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
    Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@show');
    Route::post('/account', 'AccountController@update');

    Route::get('/channel/{channel}/settings', 'ChannelController@edit');
    Route::post('/channel/{channel}/settings', 'ChannelController@update');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Auth::user()->channels()がnullなんじゃないでしょうか。
現在のユーザーがchannelsのレコードを持っているかを確認してみてください。